# After changing mysql password node server error ECONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

My code was working until I decided to change mySql password, where I did these steps:

```
sudo ./mysql -u root 

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

exit;

sudo ./mysql -u root

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'yourpasswd';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

exit;
```

I successfully changed my password where I can actually access mySQL and it has all the data that was in before the password change.

BUT

**The Problem**
my nodeJS file keeps throwing an error that looks like this

```
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

```
{
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

**My JS Snippet**

```
const mysql = require("mysql2")

module.exports = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "***",
    database: "***",
    port: 3306
})
```

The password is correct, I am very lost and would really appreciate any help

I tried deleting and reinstalling the node modules and tried
`port: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`

Comment: [here is a reliable documented way of fixing passwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html). Connection refused sounds like it isn't started.